# Delphi How to draw 2d array of TColor on TCanvas quickly?

Tags: delphi, canvas, graphics, matrix, drawing

I have a 2-dimensional array of TColor. And also I have a TCanvas. How can I draw this color map on canvas faster than with a **for** cycle?

For Example:

```
type
  T2DAr = array of array of TColor;

var
  ar: T2DAr;
  Form1: TForm; // mainform

function main;
var x, y: integer;
begin
{filling array with colors as a 10x10}

for x := 0 to length(ar)-1 do
for y := 0 to length(ar[x])-1 do
Form1.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := ar[x, y];
end;
```

This way works too slowly. I need a faster algorithm.

Comment: This has been answered many times. The answer is: use `scanline`s.

Comment: Think about two-dimensional array of TColor as a raster image. Therefore put your color matrix into bitmap and then blit it onto TCanvas. @Andreas Rejbrand, TCanvas is abstract enough to not have scanlines.

Comment: I saw the title and I immediately came in to say `scanline` but see it's already been mentioned

Comment: a little: correction: your array must be rectangular for that

Comment: or use Graphics32.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered many times. The answer is: use `scanline`s instead of the terribly slow `Pixels` property. Example:

```
function CreateBitmapReallyFast: TBitmap;
const
  WHITE: TRGBTriple = (rgbtBlue: 255; rgbtGreen: 255; rgbtRed: 255);
  BLACK: TRGBTriple = (rgbtBlue: 0; rgbtGreen: 0; rgbtRed: 0);
var
  y: Integer;
  scanline: PRGBTriple;
  x: Integer;
begin
  result := TBitmap.Create;
  result.SetSize(1920, 1080);
  result.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
  for y := 0 to result.Height - 1 do
  begin
    scanline := result.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to result.Width - 1 do
    begin
      if odd(x) then
        scanline^ := WHITE
      else
        scanline^ := BLACK;
      inc(scanline);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Even cooler:

```
with scanline^ do
begin
  rgbtBlue := Random(255);
  rgbtGreen := Random(255);
  rgbtRed := Random(255);
end;
```

To try it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  bm: TBitmap;
begin
  bm := CreateBitmapReallyFast;
  try
    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bm);
  finally
    bm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Of course, if you have a (packed) array of `TRGBTriple` or `TRGBQuad`, and the pixel format of the bitmap is the same, you can simply `Move` the data in memory from the array to the bitmap's scanlines.

Comment: No, `RGBTRIPLE` is **BGR**, `RGBQUAD` is **BGRX**, while `TColor` is **RGBX** (where X means additional pseudo-channel).

Comment: @user539484: Yeah, but that is the way it should be, IIRC.

Comment: Sure thing, but channel swapping operation is as expensive as with naive assignment. There might be some improvement if used with custom pixel format as in TIFF or BITMAPV5, where channel swapping job delegated to the other software or even hardware.

Comment: Really? Please demonstrate.

Comment: @user539484: Yeah, `TColor` might be problematic, but I never wrote anything about arrays of `TColor`, only arrays of `TRGBTriple` and `TRGBQuad`. And then there shouldn't be any need for channel swapping.

Comment: @user539484: Yeah, he wrote that. But he can most likely change his code to use the same byte order everywhere in his application, and so reduce swapping to the absolute minimum required by compatibility constraints (e.g. bitmap file formats).