# copy TBitmap to array of PByte

Tags: delphi

I want to  write a fast move  of a TBitmap  into an array of Bytes ( as  gray values). Here  is my class code snippet.  May be my error  is simple , but I did not realize how to solve it :-(  ....

```
    TGrayscaleImage = class(TGraphicControl)
      private
        /// <summary>
        ///   Byte is a pointer to a Byte. <br /><br />Note: PByte is used by the
        ///   Delphi desktop compilers, but is not supported by the Delphi mobile
        ///   compilers
        /// </summary>
        FPixels: array of PByte;
    
        public
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
        destructor Destroy; override;
        class function LoadFromFile(const FileName: string): TGrayscaleImage;
        procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    end;
    
   procedure TGrayscaleImage.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  Src: TBitmap absolute Source;
  x, y: Integer;
  P: PByte;
  xquer: Byte;
begin
  if Source is TBitmap then
  begin
    SetSize(Src.Width, Src.Height);
    for y := 0 to FHeight - 1 do
    begin
      P := Src.ScanLine[y];
      for x := 0 to FWidth - 4 do
      begin
//        xquer := Round((P^ + (P + 1)^ + (P + 2)^) / 3);
//        FPixels[y * FWidth + x] := xquer;



       // The formula for grayscale is (R + G + B) / 3
        FPixels[y][x] := (P^ + (P + 1)^ + (P + 2)^) div 3;
        Inc(P, 3);
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
    inherited Assign(Source);
end;
```

As a  reference I added the  working but extremly slow version:

```
procedure TGrayscaleImage.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  Src: TBitmap absolute Source;
  x, y: Integer;
  P: PByte;
begin
  if Source is TBitmap then
  begin
    SetSize(Src.Width, Src.Height);
    for y := 0 to FHeight - 1 do
    begin
      P := FPixels[y];
      for x := 0 to FWidth - 1 do
      begin
        P^ := (GetRValue(Src.Canvas.Pixels[x, y]) +
          GetGValue(Src.Canvas.Pixels[x, y]) + GetBValue(Src.Canvas.Pixels[x,
          y])) div 3;
        Inc(P);
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
    inherited Assign(Source);
end;
```

Comment: `FPixels` has not been assigned a size.

Comment: And `FPixels` should be declared as an `array of byte`.

Comment: You don't increase the horisontal position on the scanline (P), so you'll always only use the first pixel of each row. And how do you know that the bitmap has the right pixel format?

Comment: played with several  options but no success :-( , why is FPixels[y * FWidth + x] := xquer;  failing ?

Comment: @Franz: You need to fix the four bugs that LU RD and I found. I see that you added `Inc(P)` to address my first issue, but that won't work, since `P` is a `PByte` and therefore `Inc(P)` will step one byte, but a pixel is three or four bytes, so you need to step three or four bytes. (Which is is? Well, that depends on the pixel format, which you need to know.)

Comment: I have answered many, many scanline Qs at Stack Overflow. You can find code examples in these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33575431/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73476686/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297499/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50324516/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57726826/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4642974/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917296/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63379304/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16217886/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64860023/282848, ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72131133/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101985/282848, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20583502/282848, and probably quite a few more.

Comment: (1) You still need to change `FPixels: array of PByte;` to `FPixels: array of Byte;` (it contains greyscale bytes, not memory addresses). (2) You must allocate your dynamic array: `SetLength(FPixels, Width * Height)`. (3) You must make sure the bitmap is having the pixel format you expect (likely 24-bit). If it is wrong, you may want to convert it.